# transferring mail hosts clients having to redownload all mail

Tags: imap, pop3, mailbox

im transferring mailboxes from godaddy over to opensrs. When clients connect to their mailbox after it has been transferred they are having to re-download all their old mail to their mail client (outlook, thunderbird, etc..)

Is there a way I can log into the mailbox post transfer via telnet/pop3 and mark all the messages as read on the server. This way when the client connects for the first time they are not having to re-download all their mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on mobile so a bit brief, but in addition to the actual mail messages an IMAP server assigns unique ID numbers to messages, which are more or less  specific to that IMAP server.
By migrating  you moved the existing mail but the IMAP server generates new unique ID's and mail clients see every old message as new. Tough luck :(

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.1

> **`2.3.1.1.        Unique Identifier (UID) Message Attribute`**
>
> A 32-bit value assigned to each message, which when used with the
> unique identifier validity value (see below) forms a 64-bit value
> that MUST NOT refer to any other message in the mailbox or any
> subsequent mailbox with the same name forever.  Unique identifiers
> are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the mailbox; as each
> message is added to the mailbox it is assigned a higher UID than the
> message(s) which were added previously.  Unlike message sequence
> numbers, unique identifiers are not necessarily contiguous.
>
> The unique identifier of a message MUST NOT change during the
> session, and SHOULD NOT change between sessions.  Any change of
> unique identifiers between sessions MUST be detectable using the
> UIDVALIDITY mechanism discussed below.  Persistent unique identifiers....